# Could not autowire. No beans of 'BaseEntityRepository' type found

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseEntityRepository<T extends BaseEntity> extends CrudRepository<T, Long> {
}
```

I understand that it's logical that I can't inject the BaseEntityRepository dependency into the ServiceImpl since there is no bean created. Are there any other approaches I can use to maintain the same architecture and create the generic CRUD microService to use it in other Microservices?